# UPI using razor pay not redirect in android 13 mobile ,not get success or fail responce

Tags: payment-gateway, razorpay, android-13, upi

i used
implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.35'

but,problem with upi payments, not getting response from razorpay on either success or failure functions.
amount is getting debited from account but no response in my application.

fix it

solution for following problem..